# Decomposing $\ln(x)$ into sum of even and odd function.

Tags: functions, special-functions, graphing-functions

Can somebody help me break $\ln(x)$ into sum of even and odd function. As far as I know every function can be broken in such manner. Not being able to do this as $\ln(-x)$ and $\ln(x)$ cannot exist simultaneously.

Comment: Odd and even only make sense for functions that have a domain which is symmetric with respect to $0$. So, if $f$ is defined at $x$, it must also be defined at $-x$.

Answer (score 1):

The result you're thinking of does not work for $\ln x$ since it takes nonreal values at $x<0$. However, note that [$\mathfrak{R}(\ln x)$ is even on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5Bx%5D) (where $\mathfrak{R}z$ is the real part of $z$)